# Extract rows from a pandas dataframe between two rows

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

This is a sample of the data that I have.

```
T| 1.42 | Test1 |   1|   0 |   0
A| 1.42 |     1 |   1|   0 |   0
A| 1.42 |     1 |   2|   0 |   0
T| 1.42 | Test1 |   1|   0 |   0
A| 1.42 |     1 |   1|   0 |   0
A| 1.42 |     1 |   3|   0 |   0
A| 1.42 |     1 |   4|   0 |   0
T| 1.42 | Test1 |   1|   0 |   0
```

Is it possible to extract rows with 'A' in the first column between two rows with 'T' in first column and put into a new dataframe?

For example in this case
dataframe 1 would have

```
A| 1.42 |     1 |   1|   0 |   0
A| 1.42 |     1 |   2|   0 |   0
```

and dataframe 2 would have

```
A| 1.42 |     1 |   1|   0 |   0
A| 1.42 |     1 |   3|   0 |   0
A| 1.42 |     1 |   4|   0 |   0
```

thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very natural way to split into separate dataframes is to use `groupby`.  I find where the first column is `'T'` and use boolean indexing and `cumsum` to identify the groups.

```
m = df.iloc[:, 0].eq('T')
cumgrp = m.cumsum()[~m]
grps = df[~m].groupby(cumgrp)
```

We can see the groups and print them by iterating through them.

```
for n, g in grps:
    print(n)
    print()
    print(g)
    print()

1

   0     1  2  3  4  5
1  A  1.42  1  1  0  0
2  A  1.42  1  2  0  0

2

   0     1  2  3  4  5
4  A  1.42  1  1  0  0
5  A  1.42  1  3  0  0
6  A  1.42  1  4  0  0
```

---

You can get a list of these with

```
list_of_groups = [g for n, g in grps]
```

Comment: The use of cumsum is fascinating ! Thank you very much !